# Internet connection/WiFi not working after VPN connection failed

Tags: networking, internet, vpn

A couple of days ago I did a trial run of Cyberghost's VPN service. Have since cancelled my subscription, but that's beside the point.
My problem is: I installed the cyberghostvpn package on my Kubuntu 21.10 machine. At some point, when I tried to connect to a server, it just didn't do anything anymore (did not establish a connection, no error message, just blank in the terminal prompt). So after a couple of minutes I closed the terminal, forcing cyberghostvpn to stop.
Ever since, my internet connection is not working, no matter what connection I use.
I've tried uninstalling CyberghostVPN, but it gives me an error message (I'll try to include a photo of my screen since I have to type this on my phone). I have also reset the network manager, to no avail. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help. I am a newbie at this, so please be kind.[Screenshot of when I try to uninstall cyberghostvpn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXbf7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You probably already solved the issue, but for those that come across issues with cyberghost vpn, here is my diagnoses and solution.

When using the cli to connect to their vpn, they modify the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and add their own name server, or one they use at least. This is fine while the vpn is connected, and when you use their cli to disconnect the vpn it restores the file to the original state. The problem comes in when you connect to the vpn and shut down your pc without disconnecting.

So to resolve it try the following:

```
$ sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
$ echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo cyberghostvpn --connect --city amsterdam --country-code nl
$ sudo cyberghostvpn --stop
```

The first two steps will already solve the internet problem, and then thereafter you only restore the original file by restarting and stopping your vpn connection.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thanks for your contribution! I fear that this might break a bunch of other stuff since `/etc/resolv.conf` is supposed to be a symbolic link to a file dynamically generated by `systemd-resolve`.